# jQuery accomplish hide and show functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery , I'd like to use it to implement following two features:

- Hide Message 1 and Message 2 when the user selects Hide option from the dropdown list.
- When the user selects show, animates hidden text to show slowly and display a message inside div element after the show effect is completed.

This is my html markup example that I need to use later

```
<select id="operation">
<option value="">Select one...</option>
<option value="1">Show</option>
<option value="2">Hide</option>
</select>

<ul id="li">
<li id="x1" class="myClass1">Message 1</li>
<li id="x2" class="myClass1">Message 2</li>
<li id="x3" class="myClass2">Message 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you want the jQuery.hide and jQuery.show functions, or maybe one of the other animation functions jQuery has to offer. As for detecting the selection event, you want jQuery.on function with the appropriate event name

Comment: This isn't a code writing or tutorial service. Not hard to find lots of tutorials and learning resources to get you started. Then whan you have problmes with real code you ask questions

Comment: i want jQuery.hide and jQuery.show functions, but i'm don't know whether or which i should use jQuery.on function or not.

Comment: try my second answer i've just posted.. it works well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I can give you the most easiest answer for jQuery:

```
    <script>
    $('#operation').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '2');
      {
        $("#x2").hide();
        $("#x3").hide();

      }
      else
      {
        $("#x2").show();
        $("#x3").show();
      }
    });
    });
    </script>

<ul id="li">
<li id="x1" name="test1" class="myClass1">Message 1</li>
<li id="x2" name="test2" class="myClass1">Message 2</li>
<li id="x3" name="test3" class="myClass2">Message 3</li>
</ul>

<select id="operation">
<option value="">Select one...</option>
<option value="1">Show</option>
<option value="2">Hide</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeah,that's what i need, it's really helpful to me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#operation").change(function(){

    if ($(this).val() == "2"){ // user chose Hide

        $("#x1, #x2").hide();

    } else if ($(this).val() == "1"){ // user chose Show

        $("#x1, #x2").fadeIn('slow', function(){

            //What to do when fadeIn animation is complete
            $("#msg").html("Hi there!");

        });

    }

});
```

Untested, but it should work.